# odata4 $filter is returning false results

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I am using DataTables odata plugin to power up my html tables. When searching I am sending filter property  that looks like this :

```
$filter=    
indexof(tolower(ClientAlias/Name), 'wee') gt -1 or indexof(tolower(Product/Name), 'wee') gt -1 or indexof
(tolower(User/UserName), 'wee') gt -1 or indexof(tolower(Manager/FullName), 'wee') gt -1 and Status ne
 webapi.Models.ContractStatus'Suspended' and Manager_Id eq '120'
```

However, in the results i get absolutely everything that matches the first filters with the indexof function. For example :

```
{
ClientAlias:Object{Name="weentertain"}
Manager:
Object { Id="55"}
}
```

Where  the Manager.Id is not even close to the one that I am requesting with the Filter. 
My question is, do the previous filters overwrite the last one, or I am requesting it in a wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note that the example you gave is filtering on a property named `Manager_Id`, but no such property appears in your sample results. Did you mean to filter on `Manager/Id`?

The results you are seeing are due to [operator precedence](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc406398160). The `and` operator has higher precedence than `or`. You can override precedence by using parentheses to [group](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc406398095) the substring matches together.

Finally, you can simplify the substring matches by using the [`contains`](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc406398117) function in place of the `indexof`/`eq` combination.

Here's the rewritten filter (with line breaks inserted for readability):

```
$filter=
  (contains(tolower(ClientAlias/Name), 'wee') or
   contains(tolower(Product/Name), 'wee') or
   contains(tolower(User/UserName), 'wee') or 
   contains(tolower(Manager/FullName), 'wee')) and
  Status ne webapi.Models.ContractStatus'Suspended' and
  Manager/Id eq '120'
```